# Update text of an object in google slides using google slides API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api

I am not able to find the right way to update text of existing objects using the google slides API.

Currently I am deleting the slide and creating it again.

Answer (score 3):

How about using [`presentations.batchUpdate`](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/batchUpdate)? By using this, **the texts in the figures and on slide can be modified.** The sample script is as follows. When you use this, please enable Slide API at API console and Advanced Google Services.

### Sample script :

This sample modifies "sample text" on the slide of `pageObjectIds` to "updated text".

```
var presentationId = "### presentationId ###";
var resource = {
  "requests": [
    {
      "replaceAllText": {
        "containsText": {
          "text": "sample text"
        },
        "replaceText": "updated text",
        "pageObjectIds": ["### pageObjectIds ###"] // If this is not defined, the text is searched from all slides.
      }
    }
  ]
};
Slides.Presentations.batchUpdate(resource, presentationId);
```

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Have you ever tried to use a deleteText request in the same batchupdate with an insertText to change the text.  I coulfn't get it to work that way so I had to run them in separate batches.  I specified a range type of all but it keeping telling that startIndex had to be smaller that endIndex even though I hadn't used them at all.

Comment: @Cooper Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `use a deleteText request in the same batchupdate with an insertText to change the text.`. I apologize for this. In order to correctly understand about your question, can you provide the sample situation? By this, I would like to try to understand it.

Comment: @Cooper the range in table cells in a slide is tricky. In order to see if the cell was empty before using insertText txtBack = tblArr[0].getCell(r, c).getText().asString();
      if ( txtBack.length > 1) . Without the asString the txtBack was "txtBack:  TextRange  txtBack.length:  9.0" With the asString an empty cell has a length of 1!

Answer (score 3):

[Inserting, deleting, or replacing text](https://developers.google.com/slides/how-tos/styling#inserting_deleting_or_replacing_text) docs is what you're looking for.

There are two ways you can replace text in a presentation using the Slides API:

1. By performing a global search-and-replace.
2. By explicitly deleting and adding text. Both ways use the [batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/batchUpdate) method, but with different request types.

**Global search and replace**

Use *ReplaceAllTextRequest* to do a global search-and-replace throughout your presentation.

The Text Merging section of the Merging Data guide provides an example of how you can use this request type.

**Replacing text within a shape**

The Slides API lets you modify the text content of a shape. You can remove individual ranges of text, and you can insert text at a specific location.

Use *[InsertTextRequest](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request#inserttextrequest)* and *[DeleteTextRequest](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request#deletetextrequest)* to perform these operations.